# Ruby block `block in Method': undefined method `inject' for true:TrueClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a method that takes in a string and returns a new sentence string where every word longer than 4 characters has all vowels removed. The output should return a modified sentence string to these specs.

```
def abbreviate_sentence(sent)
  arr = []
  word = sent.split("")
  word.reject do |v|
       if word.length > 4
         arr << %w(a e i o u).any?.inject(v)
       else arr << word
       end
  end
  return arr
end
```

I get the following error and am trying to include/"inject" the modified elements into a new array in which to join into the desired string described above. If I remove "inject" I get a boolean and not the modified string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this error because you try to call [Enumerable#inject](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) method on result of [Enumerable#any?](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F) which is either `true` or `false`.

Some other small things to note:

- Calling `str.split('')` will return array of all characters and not words.
- To form result string from array of modified words you can use [Array#join](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-join) method

---

Personally, I would solve this task in following way:

```rb
def abbreviate_sentence(sentence)
  words = sentence.split # By default this method splits by whitespace
  handled_words = words.map do |w|
    if w.length > 4
      w.tr!('aeiou', '') # This method deltes all the wovels from word
    end
    w # Handled word
  end
  handled_words.join(' ') # Ruby returnes last evaluated expression automatically
end
```

Some results using `irb`:

```rb
abbreviate_sentence 'Hello there! General Kenobi' # => "Hll thr! Gnrl Knb"
abbreviate_sentence 'sample text' # => "smpl text"
```

One thing I should point out:
This method do not preserve whitespace since [String#split](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-split) is used

```rb
abbreviate_sentence "Example \n with some \t\t\t new strings \n and \t tabulations" # => "Exmpl with some new strngs and tbltns"
```